# Johnny Test episode with repressing Johnny's genes to revert him back to his ancestors' traits

Tags: episode-identification, johnny-test

Alright, so I'm thinking about an episode of *Johnny Test*. The plot of the episode was fuzzy, but it had something to do with repressing Johnny's genes in order to revert him back to having certain traits of his ancestors. I know it was a later season episode, but I can't identify any additional plot information.

Comment: https://johnnytest.fandom.com/wiki/The_Good,_the_Bad_%26_the_Johnny?

Comment: @Valorum That's not quite it. Johnny stepped in and out of the machine multiple times in the episode I'm thinking of. Each time he was a different caricature of some group each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Season 4, episode 14b, "Who's Johnny?" sounds like a match.

Summary from [Wikia](https://johnnytest.fandom.com/wiki/Who%27s_Johnny%3F):

> When Sissy considers Johnny too gross to help her with their social studies project, he begs Susan and Mary to change his personality, as part of their grade depends on cooperation and their ability to work together.

The episode is below (second part of the video, start roughly at 11 minutes). Skimming it, I heard the two redheads girls talking about not knowing whether personality comes from within or genetics, messing with DNA and stuff, and the boy gets in and out of the machine several times.

For instance, "extract the DNA helix and store it in the mainframe" (14'55).

---

Found by browsing [the summaries of all episodes](https://johnnytest.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_Guide). "Changing personality" sounded promising with regards to ancestor's traits.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's such a politically incorrect episode.